# How do I move one face 1 BU, and the nearest faces .5 BU and the faces two layers out .25 BU and so on?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertex-weights

I did this in Maya long time ago where it's just a simple mode. But can't seem to find the same thing in Blender.

The exact values/weight isn't important, it's just about figuring out the falloff.

Thanks for any response.

Comment: I guess you're looking for an equivalent to soft selection? That's proportional editing in Blender.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html

Answer (score 0):

You want the proportional editing tool, which can be accessed from the toolbar at the top, or by the shortcut <kbd>O</kbd>.

[image]

You can select the profile of the falloff from the drop down menu, and control the size using the mouse's scroll wheel.

[image]

Additionally, you can retroactively edit both the profile and the size of the fall off in the Adjust Last Operation menu that pops up after your displacement operation. You can even set a specific numerical value for the size here.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Perfect